# How to remove the dependency on jquery

Tags: vue.js, dom, vue-component

When I research on how to integrate Plotly with Vue, I found this example:

https://codepen.io/rhamner/pen/MXgWqJ

It meets my requirement, but it requires jquery js, I would like to remove the dependence of jquery js file.

I tried to add bellow code into the component

```
ref='chart_id'
```

and in the mounted() I change as bellow:

```
this.$refs.chart_id.$on('plotly_hover', this.hover);
```

But looks like it doesn't work.

How to change the code, I just think it should be able to code in another way to exclude jquery to save move time one page loading.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is only used in `mounted` for two bindings which can be easily rewritten:

```js
//...
  mounted() {
    this.Plot();
    this.$watch("data", this.Plot, { deep: true });
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.onResize);
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.onResize);
  },
  methods: {
    Plot() {
      Plotly.newPlot(this.divId, this.data, this.layout);
      this.$el.on('plotly_hover', this.hover);
    },
    //...
  }
//...
```

Since your normal `hover` event has `points` inside `event`, not inside `eventData`, you also need to modify the hover function to look for `points` in both places:

```
hover: function (event, eventData) {
  this.$emit('hover', eventData
    ? eventData.points
    : event.points,
  this.divId);
},
```

... to cover both cases.

See it working without jQuery here: https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/XWmJbYo

Comment: Found a bug: can't get the points value if the plotdata changed. Could you help to look at the code again? Thanks!  @tao

Comment: Right, because the binding is now local, not delegated through window object, so it's gone on replot. Ok, so we need to replace `this.Plot` in the watcher with a function doing both: plots and rebinds. I named it `rebind`. Check the updated pen. And, we can safely remove the `this.$el.off` in `beforeDestroy`. Updated answer, as well.

Comment: Obviously, considering current functions, you could simply move the binding inside Plot(); and disable rebind method alltogether. Because you don't have a case where you want to `Plot()` without binding. I'll update the pen.